# What is the problem of draging list on mobile using React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable

I try to create a sortable list using React Js, I use the events `onDragStart`, `onDragEnd`, `onDragOver` for this operation. The sortable list work on desktop means mouse events but on phone with touch doesn't work. I find a solution in stack overflow by set `touch-action:none;` for draggable elements but that didn't work for me, Also I find that I can use touch events `onTouchStart`, `onTouchEnd`, `onTouchMove` but that isn't that I want because the `onTouchMove` track just the touched element not all others element when `onDragOver` can track all over elements and that work better. But the problem is the phone can not track `drag` events. There is any solution to make my app work in touche devices(Phones, Tablets...).

```js
function App() {
  function dragOverHandler (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const dragging = document.querySelector('.dragging');
        const todosContainer = document.querySelector('.todos');
        todosContainer.insertBefore(dragging, e.target);
 }
 return (
 
        <div 
          key={todo.id} 
          className='todo' 
          draggable='true' 
          onDragStart={e=> e.target.classList.add('dragging')} 
          onDragEnd={e=> e.target.classList.remove('dragging')} 
          onDragOver={dragOverHandler}
        >
          <span className='check_complete complete' onClick={props.updateHandler} id={todo.id}></span>
          <h3 className='task line'>{todo.task[0].toUpperCase() + todo.task.substr(1)}</h3>
          <button className='remove' onClick={clickHandler} id={todo.id}>
            <CrossIcon style={{pointerEvents:'none'}}/>
          </button>
        </div>
 );
}
```

Comment: If you can explain me the concept that gonna be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance!!